# SQL join when a field name is the same

Tags: sql, mysql, drupal, join

I have field "language" in both node and url_alias.
When I do a dump, the second "language" variable overwrites the first one.
How can I identify both variables?

```
$string =   "SELECT * FROM {node} as node " .
            " LEFT JOIN {url_alias} as url " .
            " ON url.src = CONCAT('node/', node.nid) " .                
            " ORDER BY node.type , node.nid " ;

$result= db_query($string);
while ($row = db_fetch_object($result)){
echo $row->language;
var_dump($row);
```

Answer (score 6):

Specify the column names explicitly in your `SELECT` clause rather than using `*`, and give any duplicate column names an alias. E.g.,

```
SELECT node.nid,
    node.language as NodeLanguage,
    url.language as UrlLanguage
FROM {node} as node 
LEFT JOIN {url_alias} as url  
ON url.src = CONCAT('node/', node.nid)                 
ORDER BY node.type , node.nid
```

Comment: Thank you... I was going to do that but it was going to get very verbose. Is there a way to say "all fields" + "rename these". Or a way to prefix with the file name using this syntax?  I have seen stuff like $row->file->field in other applications.

Comment: You could write a stored procedure to do that, but I don't recommend it. If you have too many column names to type (hundreds?), there are likely design issues you need to deal with first.

Comment: dozens. lasy programer doez not like to tipe. :)

Comment: @newt: There are 28 words in your question, not counting the query and tags. You can do it!

Comment: Sometimes it takes longer to ask a question than to implement the answer.