# codeigniter misses the value of the id field from sql query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

when I execute this query, codeigniter replaces the value of the ID field with category.id

```
id | category_id | manufacturer_id | title 
1  |    4        |    12           |  symfony
2  |    4        |    16           | pioneer
3  |    4        |     93          | razer
4  |    4        |    2            | python

 $item_id = 3;

  $this->db->select("*")
            ->from("items")
            ->join("category", "category.id=items.category_id")
            ->where("items.id", $item_id);
  var_dump($this->db->get->result_object());
```

What it returns is

```
 stdClass::__set_state(array(
 'id' => '4',
 'category_id' => '4',
 'manufacturer_id' => '1',
 'title' => 'Floral Swing Dress',
 'image_file_name' => 'c62e854fe16c8cc60e508a423f9a14da.jpg',
 'price' => '84',
 'type' => 'evening_dress',
 'parent_id' => '2',
  )),
```

The value of id is being replaced with the value of category_id . the id should be 3, but its now 4.

when I execute the query in phpmyadmin I get the correct results.

Comment: you may need to select individual colms instead of * and perhaps using the alias

Comment: I have to use alias, but it doesnt makes sense why would it replace the ID...

Comment: do category and items table both has id column if yes then u need to.

Comment: thats answers so u need to use alias which one u need to get http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280723/sql-join-when-a-field-name-is-the-same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077998/problem-in-php-when-joining-tables-having-columns-with-the-same-name http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530218/mysql-left-join-and-column-with-the-same-name-in-different-tables

Comment: I have to find a way, to use * for the remaining columns, just use alias for the id column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
$this->db->select("items.*, category.id as cat_id, category.otherfieldname")
        ->from("items")
        ->join("category", "category.id=items.category_id")
        ->where("items.id", $item_id);
```